# Function Declaration Parameter Naming Best Practices (C++)

Tags: c++, function

In a function declaration, while the parameters do not have to be named, is it preferable to have them named? What are the advantages and disadvantages of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The advantage of naming them is that you can refer to them in the documentation. (This includes your editor/IDE picking them up and presenting them to you as hints when you type a call to such a function.)

A disadvantage would be that names might change according to the function's implementation, except for the fact that the names in a function declaration might differ from those in the function's definition. (IOW: I see no disadvantage.)

Comment: +1 but you might also mention that if you put variable names in a declaration, IntelliSense (or whatever you might have) can pick them up.  This is nothing more than documentation, but a useful elaboration of it.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Indeed, I forgot about that!

Answer (score 3):

For documentation reasons mainly

Comment: Maintenance is also easier if the definition and declaration are identical (give or take a semicolon)

Answer (score 3):

Naming parameters has a significant advantage when you work with IDEs that support auto-completion. When you start typing the name of your function, the IDE pops up a list of suggestions. Seeing `findUser(string firstName, string lastName)` tells you a lot more than simply `findUser(string,string)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a question of style. Personally, if I see a function declaration without named parameters, I find it hard to read. I think the more strong you can type C++, the better it is.

Answer (score 1):

One advantage is that they can convey more information when parameter types are the same

Consider

```
CoordSystem CreateCoordinateSystem( const UnitVector& xdirection, 
    const UnitVector& ydirection, const UnitVector& zdirection
)
```

over

```
CoordSystem CreateCoordinateSystem( const UnitVector& , 
    const UnitVector& , const UnitVector& )
```

Answer (score 0):

In the declaration there aren't really any programmatic advantages or disadvantages. However, there is one style advantage that I can think of:

When you don't use a parameter in a function, you can not name this parameter in the declaration AND the definition:

```
void foo(int);

void foo(int)
{
}
```

Naming parameters that you don't use in the definition isn't illegal, but it is a lint warning! The style advantage that I mentioned would be not naming the parameters in the declaration so that someone who is browsing a header file will know that a certain parameter is not being used in the definition. However, this is only if you synchronize the not-named-ness between the definition and the declaration.

Here's an example of when you might want to not name a parameter:

```
class Base
{
    virtual void foo(int a) = 0;
};

class Child1
{
    virtual void foo(int a) { std::cout << a + 1 << std::endl; }
};

class Child2
{
    virtual void foo(int) { std::cout << "mwahaha" << std::endl; }
};
```

In this case, the parameter isn't named, but still must be supplied because the function prototype must match that of its parent.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but this doesn't exactly apply.  The question was specifically about naming parameters in **declarations**, but the (valid) point you make applies only to function **definitions**.